# Modifier.align for PlainTooltipBox

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
Box {
    PlainTooltipBox {
        // button
    }
    // content
}
```

I'm trying to align the button using Modifier.align, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've already tried applying the Modifier.align to the PlainTooltipBox's modifier, but it didn't have the desired effect. Can someone please help me understand how to properly align the button within the PlainTooltipBox using Modifier.align?

Comment: Can you add more code for better insights? I'm not able to understand your requirement

Comment: show what PlainTooltipBox is, please?